# build a binary string c++

Tags: c++, string, binary

How do I build a binary string in c++?

I want to have it in this format:

```
  std::string str = signed long (4bytes) "fill out zeros" 0x000 (8bytes) signed long (4bytes)
```

Note I DO NOT want the viewable binary representation but the actual binary data in the string

Comment: IMHO the best thing is to manage a `uint8_t*` in an explicit way (either by writing the individual bytes by means of bitshifts and explicit endianess or by resorting to unaligned integer load/store), possibly wrapped in a `std::array<uint8_t>`.

Comment: Though I still need it resulting in a string... Would it work to shift into a char that you later append to the string?

Comment: Why do you want this in a `std::string`? It's not a sequence of characters; it's an arbitrary array of bytes. So use a `std::vector<uint8_t>`.

Comment: "Note I DO NOT want the viewable binary representation but the actual binary data in the string" What does this mean?

Comment: I meant that I don´t want the printable string containing chars of "1" and "0" ("11111100 ... ")  but the ascii (11111100) value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your specific application:

```
std::string data(12, 0);  // construct string of 12 null-bytes

int32_t x, y;  // populate

char const * const p = reinterpret_cast<char const *>(&x);
char const * const q = reinterpret_cast<char const *>(&y);

std::copy(p, p + 4, data.begin()    );
std::copy(q, q + 4, data.begin() + 8);
```

Comment: Thanks! It was something like this I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
char buffer[1024];
// fill up buffer with whatever
char *end = afterLastChar;
std:string s(buffer, afterLastChar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use std::vector< uint8_t >, this is not a string